AWSAPPSync I'm operating in the console and can't subscribe to my own messages
The question is as follows：enter image description hereenter image description here 我查询没有问题，唯独订阅的时候就报错，I also configured both the data source and the parser
As follows:
I have been trying to configure security, but there is still an error, do not know the type of error, can not judge, see if you can help me solve this type of error
This problem seems difficult to solve. I tested it with the console. The data on the app is the same as the error on the console, and the error type cannot be located.
Is there a good way to help me solve this problem.

Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly. See Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Please translate everything into english.
